# Simplifying x Conjugate[x]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I am trying to simplify a big expression containing many times terms of the form  `x  Conjugate[x]`. While this works for a single term:

```
FullSimplify[a  Conjugate[a]]
(* Out: Abs[a]^2 *)
```

it does not work for combines expressions:

```
FullSimplify[  Conjugate[a] y  Conjugate[y]]
(* Out: y Conjugate[a] Conjugate[y] *)
```

I have tried rearranging and `MapAll` with no improvement.

Any hints on what I could do?

Comment: Try replacement `Rule`s maybe, like `expr //
. HoldPattern[Times[x_, y__, Conjugate[x_]]] :> Times[Abs[x]^2, y]`.

Comment: @march, `Times` is `Flat` so you don't need to include the y__ bit of the pattern. `expr //. x_ Conjugate[x_] :> Abs[x]^2`

Comment: @SimonWoods. The `Flat` `Attribute` gives me trouble sometimes, especially in replacement rules with `Plus` and `Times`, where I have to worry about pre-evaluation; thus the `HoldPattern`. But I guess I should have tested the simplest possibility first!

Answer (score 8):

I suspect that the reason why your simplifications work differently lies in the `LeafCount` of their outputs, which is a major contributor to the complexity function that the `*Simplify` functions use by default.

Consider for instance:

```
FullSimplify[Conjugate[a] a b]  (* Out: a b Conjugate[a]*)
% // LeafCount                  (* Out: 5 *)

Abs[a^2] b //LeafCount          (* Out: 6 *)
```

Crucially, the `LeafCount` of the "simpler" expression containing `Abs` is actually higher (see its `FullForm`), so it won't be selected as the simplest by `FullSimplify`.

The first approach I tried was to modify the complexity function to include a penalty for the presence of multiple `Conjugate` expressions:

```
FullSimplify[y a Conjugate[y] Conjugate[a], 
 ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 100 Count[#, _Conjugate, {0, Infinity}] &)
]

(* Out: a y Conjugate[a] Conjugate[y] *)
```

As you can see, no joy there. This is probably because no version containing fewer `Conjugate` expressions was even generated as a candidate during the internal evaluation of `FullSimplify`.

We can try to nudge `FullSimplify` in the right direction using an approach similar to the one march outlined in comments, while still maintaining the rest of the `FullSimplify` machinery, by adding a custom transformation function (see [`TransformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions.html) in the docs) to apply to the expressions to be simplified:

```
FullSimplify[y a Conjugate[y], 
 ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 100 Count[#, _Conjugate, {0, Infinity}] &),
 TransformationFunctions -> {
   Automatic,
   Function[{expr}, ReplaceAll[expr, Times[a__, Conjugate[b_], b_] :> Times[a, Abs[b^2]]]]
 }
]

(* Out: a Abs[y]^2 *)
```

Finally! A note: using `Automatic` in the list of trasnformation functions lets `FullSimplify` use anything from its usual bag of tricks, and simply adds our own custom function.

So let's make this into a handy function:

```
conjSimplify = (FullSimplify[#,
    ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 100 Count[#, _Conjugate, {0, Infinity}] &),
    TransformationFunctions -> {
      Automatic,
      Function[{expr}, ReplaceAll[expr, Times[a__, Conjugate[b_], b_] :> Times[a, Abs[b^2]]]]
    }
 ] &);


conjSimplify[a b x Conjugate[a] Conjugate[b]]
(* Out: x Abs[a b]^2 *)
```

Comment: With Simplify instead of FullSimplify it works for my more complex expressions too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @wolfgang6444 Excellent! I'm curious though: `Simplify` worked better for you? Was that because `FullSimplify` got bogged down on the more complex expression, or it returned an expression, but it just wouldn't give you the desired result? In any case, I'm glad that it worked out!

Comment: No wrong or unwanted results - FullSimplify just didn't finish

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned using [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand) with `TargetFunctions->{Abs}`, possibly with an assist from [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify):

```
ComplexExpand[a  Conjugate[a], _, TargetFunctions->{Abs}]
```

> Abs[a]^2

```
Simplify @ ComplexExpand[Conjugate[a] y  Conjugate[y], _, TargetFunctions->{Abs}]
```

> (Abs[a]^2 Abs[y]^2)/a

```
Simplify @ ComplexExpand[Conjugate[a] a b, _, TargetFunctions->{Abs}]
```

> b Abs[a]^2

```
ComplexExpand[y a Conjugate[y] Conjugate[a], _, TargetFunctions->{Abs}]
```

> Abs[a]^2 Abs[y]^2

```
Simplify @ ComplexExpand[y a Conjugate[y], _, TargetFunctions->{Abs}]
```

> a Abs[y]^2

```
Simplify @ ComplexExpand[a b x Conjugate[a] Conjugate[b], _, TargetFunctions->{Abs}]
```

> x Abs[a]^2 Abs[b]^2