# Scope of Simplifying Complex Expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Do you know what the scope of Mathematica's simplification capabilities for complex expressions is? For example, I put the heavy lifting of proving a complex inequality on Mathematica, using the following code:

```
Clear[u, v, z, w]
$Assumptions = u \[Element] Complexes && v \[Element] Complexes;
z = (1 + u Conjugate[u]) v - (1 + v Conjugate[v]) u;
w = u Conjugate[v] - v Conjugate[u];
result = FullSimplify[z Conjugate[z] - w Conjugate[w]]
```

resulting, quite sensibly, in

```
(u-v) (-1+v Conjugate[u]) (Conjugate[u]-Conjugate[v]) (-1+u Conjugate[v])
```

but I cannot coerce in into recognizing the two absolute values. Should Mathematica be able to "see" this, or can I give it a "rule" which may allow it so "see" this pattern as it occurs (similar to the trigonometric Pythagoras, say)?

Edited to add (1): **No, the link does not answer my question.**

[image]

The output should ideally be

```
Abs[u-v]^2 Abs[1-Conjugate[u]v]^2
```

**Edited to add** (2): The best I can come up with, **which does not use the link offered by the commenter** as it is useless for the case I inquired about, is the following. Whatever.

Starting with the output from above,

```
result = (u-v) (-1+v Conjugate[u]) (Conjugate[u]-Conjugate[v]) (-1+u Conjugate[v]),
```

the goal is to identify complex-conjugate pairs in this product and write the result as a list of norm-squares. To that end,

```
terms=List@@result;
combos=Flatten[Table[{t1,t2},{t1,terms},{t2,terms}],{1,2}];
conjugatePairs=Union[Map[Sort[#]&,Cases[combos,x_/;x[[1]]==Conjugate[x[[2]]]]]]
Product[Abs[t]^2,{t,conjugatePairs[[All,1]]}]
```

Giving

```
Out[512]= Abs[u-v]^2 Abs[-1+v Conjugate[u]]^2
```

without manual copy-and-paste or typing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplifying x Conjugate\[x\]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119752/simplifying-x-conjugatex) Also, can you please write down exactly what output you are expecting?

Comment: It does not answer my question. The output resulting from the answer to that question is remote from what it should be mathematically. See my edit above.